# Sum 2 Big Integers store in array by using getchar not scanf - C programing

Tags: c, arrays, getchar

I need a help with this program, below is the object and the program I wrote so far:

Objective: Write a C program that allow user 100 digit positive integers and then print out the sum of the two numbers.

Program I wrote so far by using **scanf**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

int sum=0,i,j,array[100];



for(i=1;i<3;i++)
{
printf("operand #%d :",i);
scanf("%d",&array[i]);
printf("value entered: %d\n", array[i]);
}



for(j=1;j<i;j++)
{
sum=sum+array[j];
}



printf("The sum of array is %d ", sum);

return 0;
}
```

The following is the code I used **getchar()**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

int c,i,j,sum=0;

char a[100];

for(i=1;i<3;i++)
{
printf("operand #%d :",i);


do{
    if(i < 100){
        a[i] = (char)c;
        i++;
        }
    else{
      printf("Error: Number must be greater than 0,try again");
    }
} while((c = getchar()) != '\n');


printf("value entered: %d\n", a[i]);
}



for(j=1;j<i;j++)
{
sum=sum+a[j];
}



printf("The sum of array is %d ", sum);

return 0;
}
```

Any help is appropriate!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  You're trying to use the variable `i` for two different jobs at the same time; it won't work properly. You're going to need 3 separate strings to store the three numbers.  You're going to be reading the numbers from most to least significant digit, but the lengths could be 80, 60 and 20 characters.  You'll have to sort out a way so that the 80th, 60th and 20th digits are added; then the 79th, 59th and 19th (plus the carry), and so on.  You need to do some more thinking, I think.

Comment: First thing, when you use do while, the first time ou enter the loop, c has not been assigned. a[1] could be anything, and more important, out of your control.
And the most critical is messing with yout i variable, as @JonathanLeffler said

Comment: And remember that getchar, as the name suggests, gets char data. If you assing int a = char c, a will be the ASCII code of c, and not the number it's representing

Comment: Please do not blank out your question the way you did again as it undermines the effort that Jonathan Leffler has put into helping you.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that you're using `i` for two different jobs at the same time.  It isn't going to work.

```
for(i=1;i<3;i++)  // Use #1
{
    printf("operand #%d :",i);

    do{
        if(i < 100){
            a[i] = (char)c;  // Use #2
            i++;
            }
        else{
          printf("Error: Number must be greater than 0,try again");
        }
    } while((c = getchar()) != '\n');

    printf("value entered: %d\n", a[i]);
}
```

The outer loop will probably execute just once — it would execute twice if the first number was a single-digit number.

This code also assigns `c` before you've called `getchar()`, which is not going to improve things, either.  You probably also need to convert the ASCII digits into single-digit numbers (subtract `'0'` from the digits but you should check that it is a digit first, and should break the inner loop on a non-digit).

If you're going to store 3 numbers of up to 100 digits each, you're going to need to have storage for up to 300 digits.  `char a[100]` isn't big enough.

You might use something like:

```
char a[3][100];
int  n[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int c;
    int j;
    printf("Operand #%d: ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < 100 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c); j++)
        a[i][j] = c - '0';
    n[i] = j;
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}
```

If you enter numbers with 80, 60 and 20 digits, then this stores the 80 digits in `a[0][0..79]` and puts `80` into `n[0]` (so you know how long the number is); it stores the 60 digits in `a[1][0..59]` and puts `60` into `n[1]`; and it stores the 20 digits in `a[2][0..19]` and puts `20` into `n[2]`.

When it comes to doing the addition, you need to be careful to align the numbers correctly, and ensure that you don't overflow the answer buffer if your addition has 101 digits.  With three positive decimal numbers of up to 100 digits each, the answer can't be more than 101 digits long.

---

> However, your code doesn't work.

True: the previous version use `for (int j = 0; …)` and then tried to access `j` outside the loop.  The fix is obviously to declare `j` before the loop.

However, otherwise, the code does work.  I've adjusted the occurrences of 3 to 2 since you say you only need two numbers.  I decline to mess with indexing from 1; this is C and arrays are indexed from 0 in C.  If you want a 1-based language, go and use Pascal or something.

Sample code to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[2][100];
    int n[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int c;
        int j;
        printf("Operand #%d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < 100 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c); j++)
            a[i][j] = c - '0';
        n[i] = j;
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
            c = getchar();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %2d digits: ", i, n[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
            putchar(a[i][j] + '0');
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample data:

```
124232345289086098234232398098403242380980256454798796324635
98068704234280980243242349080928402342398408920482080980482034278795847396
```

Sample output:

```
Operand #0: 124232345289086098234232398098403242380980256454798796324635
Operand #1: 98068704234280980243242349080928402342398408920482080980482034278795847396
0: 60 digits: 124232345289086098234232398098403242380980256454798796324635
1: 74 digits: 98068704234280980243242349080928402342398408920482080980482034278795847396
```

That's the way it is supposed to work.  You may want to do it differently; that's your prerogative.  Have at it!  I'm not going to solve the addition part of the problem for you — I've pointed out the most obvious gotchas (primarily, adding `a[0][1]` to `a[1][1]` will produce nonsense for the given inputs).

---

This only uses tiny functions.  There's some tricky code in it; be wary of handing it in because you might be asked to explain what it does in detail, and you'll need to understand it all to be safe.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int max(int x, int y) { return (x > y) ? x : y; }

/* Return dth digit from RH end of string of n digits in x */
static inline int digit(char *x, int n, int d)
{
    return (d < n) ? x[n - 1 - d] : 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[2][100];
    int n[2];

    /* Input - can probably be tightened up */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int c;
        int j;
        printf("Operand #%d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < 100 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c); j++)
            a[i][j] = c - '0';
        n[i] = j;
        if (j == 0)
        {
            printf("No number - exiting\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        if (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        {
            if (j < 100 && !isdigit(c) && !isblank(c))
            {
                printf("Bogus data in input (%c)\n", c);
                exit(1);
            }
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            {
                if (!isblank(c))
                {
                    printf("Bogus data in input (%c)\n", c);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Print for validation */
    int n_max = max(n[0], n[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("V-%d: %2d digits: ", i, n[i]);
        int n_blanks = n_max - n[i] + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < n_blanks; j++)
            putchar(' ');
        for (int j = 0; j < n[i]; j++)
            putchar(a[i][j] + '0');
        putchar('\n');
    }

    /* Addition */
    char sum[101];
    int carry = 0;
    int max_digits = max(n[0], n[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_digits; i++)
    {
        int d0 = digit(a[0], n[0], i);
        int d1 = digit(a[1], n[1], i);
        int r = d0 + d1 + carry;
        if (r > 9)
        {
            carry = 1;
            r -= 10;
        }
        else
            carry = 0;
        sum[max_digits - i] = r;
    }
    if (carry)
        sum[0] = 1;
    else
        sum[0] = 0;

    /* Print result */
    printf("Sum: %2d digits: ", (sum[0] == 0) ? max_digits : max_digits + 1);
    if (sum[0] == 0)
        putchar(' ');
    for (int j = ((sum[0] == 0) ? 1 : 0); j <= max_digits; j++)
        putchar(sum[j] + '0');
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
Operand #0: 888
Operand #1: 888
V-0:  3 digits:  888
V-1:  3 digits:  888
Sum:  4 digits: 1776


Operand #0: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Operand #1: 9876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
V-0: 100 digits:  1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
V-1: 100 digits:  9876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
Sum: 101 digits: 11111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111101111111110111111111011111111100

Operand #0: 9876543210a
Bogus data in input (a)


Operand #0: 9876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210a
Bogus data in input (a)

Operand #0: 98765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109
Bogus data in input (9)

Operand #0: 
No number - exiting
```

It isn't perfect:

```
Operand #0: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Operand #1: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
V-0: 100 digits:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
V-1: 100 digits:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Sum: 100 digits:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Stripping leading zeroes from input (and output) is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: Since I can't undelete comments that were deleted by their authors for whatever reason the only other option is to remove the rest.

Comment: Fair enough; probably best. The relevant information is now in the answer, anyway.